# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to type 'Blogosphere.Models.Users'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello everyone,

I've searched and searched for how to do this.

I have a domain model called Posts.cs below

```
public class Posts
{
    [Key]
    public int PostID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="A Title is required for your Post")]
    [Display(Name="Title")]
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage="This Field is Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Post")]
    public string PostContent { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    //public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    //public int CommentID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual List<Comments> Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual Users user { get; set; }

}
```

so I created a viewModel called PostsVM.cs so as to present it to the view and get the PostTitle and PostContent since they are the only fields that need editing

```
public class PostsVM
{
    [Required()]
    [Display(Name="Title")]
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    [Display(Name="Post")]
    public string PostContent { get; set; }
}
```

Since a post belongs to a user hence the line

```
public virtual Users user { get; set; }
```

in the Posts.cs class. That is when I'm saving the Posts to the database I must save it along with the user ID which is the author of the posts. and my controller looks like this

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    PostsVM model = new PostsVM();
    return View(model);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PostsVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Model");
    }
    BlogContext db = new BlogContext();
    var newPost = db.Post.Create();

    newPost.PostTitle = model.PostTitle;
    newPost.PostContent = model.PostContent;
    newPost.PostDate = DateTime.Now;
    FormsIdentity identity = (FormsIdentity)User.Identity;
    int nUserID = Int32.Parse(identity.Ticket.UserData);
    newPost.user = Int32.Parse(identity.Ticket.UserData);
    db.Post.Add(newPost);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Posts");

}
```

what I tried to do was to get the userId from the userData i stored in the ticket and convert it to integer type in the line

```
newPost.user = Int32.Parse(identity.Ticket.UserData);
```

however, this line above appears as a red squiggy line with the error `"Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to type 'Blogosphere.Models.Users'.`
  So i tried to do this

```
newPost.user.UserID = Int32.Parse(identity.Ticket.UserData);
```

but I debugged with a breakpoint on this line and I got an error saying

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

I know it is wrong to do it this way since it will be accessing all of the properties of the User.cs class. Please how can I get the user id in the userdata I stored in the ticket and save it in the

```
public virtual Users user { get; set; } property of the Posts.cs class?
```

somebody help please. StackOverflow has been so helpful. Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `newPost.user` property is not initialized, and accessing `newPost.user.UserID` will throw "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: what do you mean by the newPost.user is not initialized. I was just trying to save the userId in the ticket to the user property of the Posts.cs class since thats the property refering to the author of the post which i did with the newPost.user = Int32.Parse(identity.Ticket.UserData); so what initialization does it needs again?

Comment: your first attempt did not work because you are setting a property of type Users with a value of type Int32.

Comment: how should i do it correctly. Please help with a code.

Comment: replace 

public virtual Users user { get; set; }

with 

 [Required()]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

Comment: with what should i replace public virtual Users user?